# checking out all git tags

Tags: git

I'm currently contemplating migrating to git but can't seem to find an elegant solution to the way we currently use svn tags. In my current repository I have

```
tags
tags/1
tags/1.1
tags/1.n
tags/live
tags/library
tags/library/1
tags/library/2
```

where 1-1.n are the releases, I merge the latest release into live and library contains the libraries each version may use. I understand how to create the 1.n tags in git but am struggling to see how to create the live and library tags.

Should I have a separate repo for this and pull in the tags from 1-1.n as sub modules, or can git directly do this?

Comment: If something changes over history, then it shouldn't be tag. And libraries shouldn't be in their tag. They should be either part of normal structure of the repository or in different repository. In other words, you have a mess on your hands and it might not be easy to convert this to git in a ways that would make sense.

Comment: In svn this folder structure works for our deployment stack and allows us to run different versions on the same machine - I get that this is not the best structure but it works well for what we need to do.

Comment: @JakeStride the problem is that the things that you're calling tags in svn *aren't tags* and can't be used as tags in a VCS that actually knows what tags are. It's just that svn is ignorant and lets you call any old thing a tag.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that `live` should be a branch, not a tag. Just in case you're not aware: unlike svn, which treats branch and tags alike as simple tree copy operations (with the only distinction being the conventions you use in working with them), git's branches and tags are simply pointers to specific commits, the primary distinction being that the active branch follows commits, whereas tags always stay on the commit they were created against.

The library directory isn't a branch or a tag. It could possibly be replaced by git submodules, but they're tricky little buggers to work with, so you might want to steer clear of them until you've ramped your skills up a bit in general git workflow. Don't get me wrong; submodules are precisely the right tool for managing third-party dependencies, but they do take some getting used to, and will seem utterly mysterious and broken if you don't have a strong intuition about the underlying git model.

Speaking in more general terms, the big thing you lose when going from svn to git is the convenience of a pre-established workflow. Git lets you follow the common svn workflows and much, much more, but you can easily make scrambled eggs of your history if you don't adopt some kind of constraints on how you use git. You can find a very effective workflow [here](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). It isn't the only possible workflow, and it may not even be the best for your situation, but it might serve as a starting point from which you build your own workflow. E.g., at our shop, which also moved from svn, we stuck to doing most of our commits on `master`, for which they use the `develop` branch, and we tag things on a `release` branch instead of their `master`. Thus our workflow is basically the same as theirs, but with a different choice of names for the long-lived branches.

Comment: Thanks, that is really helpful and a great start but it sounds like git won't actually allow us to do what we want as we want all of those tags in one directory at the same time.

Comment: @JakeStride, in git, tags are not in any directory. You have your repository and tags are pointers to specific commits in your repository. This works fin in git, because commits in git aren't linear: one commit can have several predecessors and successors.

Comment: @JakeStride: You're right, but you shouldn't generally need to have directories represent tags. Tags are just a way to mark a particular commit with a meaningful name. You can list tags as easily as `git tag` and check out a tag with `git checkout <tagname>`. You can even have multiple working copies at different tags by using `git clone <mainrepo> <tagrepo>; cd <tagrepo>; git checkout <tagname>`. If there are other use cases you need to support, you might want to add them to your question; I'll be surprised if git can't do something you need.